# Can I use randomForest in R for hierarchical data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, hierarchical-data

I am wondering what actually happens if I include variables on two levels in a random forest model with the R-package randomForest. I am familiar with using logistical regression on multilevel data where you have to specify the levels. Is there anything similar with random forest? Or can I just put Country-level variables and Individual-level variables in the same random forest model and compare the importance of all the variables?

Would appreciate som help on this.

Comment: If you search for mixed-effects random forest model in R, you'll find a number of articles. However, I haven't found an actual R package that implements a mixed effects random forest in R. You can still use the `randomForest` package for your data. Your model will be analogous to a traditional linear regression where every variable is a "fixed effect", in contrast to a multi-level model where individuals would be clustered within countries in a hierarchical model. So the model with `randomForest` wouldn't take advantage of information implicit in the hierarchical structure of the data.

Answer (score 1):

The `randomForest` package supports two modes: regression and classification.  In regression mode, the model you build will essentially behave like a continuous function.  In this case, you would be building the model to predict numerical responses.  In classification mode, the model would predict one of many classes.  I believe that if you run `randomForest` using a factor as the response variable, it will automatically use regression mode.  Which mode you use really depends on the type of data you have.  Are you predicting something like sales, which tends to be continuous?  Or, are you predicting a group of a well defined classes?

With regard to mixing country and individual level variables in the same model, I think this does not make good sense.  You should probably be doing an individual level analysis separately from a country level analysis.  An exception might be if you plan to aggregate many individuals over each country, and then run a country level analysis.

Comment: I am using random forest for classification (dichotomous Y) and want to compare the importance of variables on different levels as on would with a hierarchical logistical model.

Comment: Are the response you are trying to predict categorical, or could they be described numerically?

Comment: Spesifically, I am trying to predict tolerance for homosexuality (categorical individual level outcome) by using both Individual-level variables (such as education) and Country-level variables (such as GDP).

Comment: You don't need to overthink this.  Now I'm not sure if you are asking whether you can use factors as _inputs_ or whether you can use them as the _response_.  Well, you can use them in both places.  `randomForest` has a bit of black box feel, in that you can just pass in your predictors and response, and it will go off and build a model for you.

Comment: Mixed-effects random forest could be interesting for you: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949655.2012.741599

Comment: Okei. Its just that with hierarchical logistical models one must specify the different levels and specify for each variable which level it belongs to. There is nothing like this when using random forest?

Comment: @RubenBergeMathisen Please update your question and show us meaningful samples of the data you are you using, along with the data for what you are trying to predict for each footprint.

Comment: "I believe that if you run randomForest using a factor as the response variable, it will automatically use regression mode." - I think you may have just inadvertently stated the reverse of what you meant to. Typically, if the response is not character/factor it will run as regression, but warn you if it detects only a handful of unique values.

Comment: @joran Yes, I meant the opposite, though my answer uses the correct language.  Factor response means classification mode.